# I bought a used 20 inch bmx bike from bike shop but no one has any idea of the brand

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, bmx

Could someone help me narrow this down?

I bought a new-used bike from local bike shop in Sacramento, California, USA. I do not know what brand it is and so were the bike shop.

There are no stickers because the bike was painted. The only things is the head tube logo which is engraved into the bike, or it has a 3D effect because it pops out.  Not sure what that would be called.  It looks like a giant logo but instead of the wave go through it side to side.   Iimagine if you just turned it to where it was up and down if that makes any sense.

The bottom bracket is sealed as well as in the neck.  I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me identify this frame.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

**Verde BMX** at http://verdebmx.com/completes/

They appear to be based in Columbus, Ohio, USA.

[image]

Method:

1. I did a google image search for "BMX logo leaf" because it looks like a leaf to me
2. One of the images is this, which looks kind of similar
3. Following the link to their web site gave me this answer

Answer (score 3):

The bike is most likely a [Verde Theory (from 2014)](http://verdebmx.com/completes/2014-theory/) IIRC, these were the only models that had the embossed Verde leaf on the head tube.

Source: I've been riding mostly Verde bikes and parts since 2011, have seen my fair share of parts and know the branding fairly well.